Two DC busses for one AC application, how to balance/share
I have two 28 VDC busses from generators.  (Not simply vicors with a sense pin to make use of).  I have an AC device which requires more power than a single bus can deliver.  How do I make this work?
Approach 1 would be to have each DC bus feed an AC inverter, these two inverters then need synchronization system so that they are in phase and the ouputs can be combined in order to supply the load.  I know there are some inverters which have this feature (either for synchronizing single phase, or for creating 3-phase AC.)
Approach 2 would be to have a single larger AC inverter, and simply connect both DC busses to the input of this inverter.  However, my concern is that the two busses may not share the load well, as there could be small voltage differences between them.  Especially as there will be a couple other smaller devices on each of those busses.
From what I can tell though, because the voltage from each generator will droop as more current is drawn (I've observed under separate 40A loads they each droop over 1 V), maybe with no load Bus 1 is 0.1 or 0.2 V higher than Bus 2, so if a small load is applied it will pull current exclusively from Bus 1, but as Bus 1 droops it becomes even with Bus 2 and thus any moderate or heavy load will be split between the two (with just a bit more on Bus 1 but not a lot).  Is this roughly correct?  Or is this really hard to say without directly experimenting to find out, and is the two sync'd inverters the 'safer' approach?  Or I've seen some approaches using current-limiting resistors but that seems unnecessary in this case.

Paralleling two DC buses in a single inverter directly can be risky due to potential voltage differences that may cause circulating currents between the buses. Even small voltage discrepancies, e.g. 0.1V as you mentioned, can result in significant currents flowing from the higher voltage bus to the lower voltage one, potentially leading to overcurrent situations and equipment damage. Relying on the natural voltage droop characteristics of the generators for load sharing is unpredictable and may not ensure balanced current distribution, especially when other devices are connected to the buses.
Using two synchronized inverters is the safer and more reliable approach. By having each DC bus feed its own inverter and synchronizing the outputs, you can combine the AC outputs to supply the load without the risks associated with paralleling the DC buses. Many modern inverters are designed with synchronization capabilities, allowing them to operate in parallel safely and efficiently. The only caveat with this could be cost and system real-estate.

Thanks, Would simpy using diodes prevent the current flowing from one DC bus into the other bus?  Also I was unable to find inverters with sync capabilities except one manufacturer and then speaking to them they said they're unsure if it even works (?!).  Can you name some of the inverter suppliers which have this feature?
